# MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx returns 87 in VB6

Tags: winapi, service, vb6

i am currently writing a service in VB6 for a real legacy application.
I am basing my work on Sergey Merzlikin "NT service sample" (http://www.smsoft.ru/en/ntservice.htm).

Until today I used NTSVC.OCX but it seems it does not work on Windows Server core because it involves a form in an ActiveX (i suppose).

So i jumped to full Winapi service and mainly i have a problem on :

MsgWaitforMultipleObjectsEx, it returns 87 (invalid parameter)
This API seems extremely tricky.

The original code uses MsgWaitForMultipleObjects but it resulted in an app crash (c0000005) in MSVBVM60.dll.
Testing platform : Windows 2012

I tweaked quite a bit the declarations, so maybe i made something wrong.
Anyway, here are the most relevant parts of the code :

```
Private Declare Function MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx Lib "user32" _
   (ByVal nCount As Long, pHandles As Long, _
    ByVal dwMilliseconds, _
    ByVal dwWakeMask As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function CreateEvent2 Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateEventW" 
   (ByVal lpEventAttributes As Long, _ 
   ByVal bManualReset As Long, _
   ByVal bInitialState As Long, _
   ByVal lpName As String) As Long

hStopEvent = CreateEvent2(0&, 1&, 0&, vbNullString)
hStopPendingEvent = CreateEvent2(0&, 1&, 0&, vbNullString)
hStartEvent = CreateEvent2(0&, 1&, 0&, vbNullString)
ServiceNamePtr = StrPtr(Service_Name)
```

I checked the handles values, they seem OK, but i suspect that they have no security descriptor with "SYNCHRONIZE"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

then there is a wrapper called MsgWaitObj in the sample NT Service. this is where I replaced MsgWaitForMultipleObjects with :

```
MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(nObj, hObj, T1, QS_ALLEVENTS, 0&)
```

The wrapper function declaration is :

```
Public Function MsgWaitObj(ByVal Interval As Long, _
        Optional ByRef hObj As Long, _
        Optional ByVal nObj As Long = 0&) As Long
```

The external declaration of MsgWaitObj in Main and the references passed are as follows :

```
hnd = NTService.StartAsService
h(0) = hnd
h(1) = hStartEvent
j(0) = hStopPendingEvent

<...>

IsNTService = MsgWaitObj(INFINITE, h(0), 2&)

<...>

Do

tm = MsgWaitObj(5000&, j(0), 1&)

Loop While tm = WAIT_TIMEOUT
```

I hope posting excerpts of code is sufficient, if not i think the easiest way would be to download the ntservice sample and figure what is going wrong and if i am in the right path or not.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Not an answer but... NTSVC.OCX does indeed work on servers and I just retested on a Win Server 2008 R2 SP1 box.  If Server Core is the problem then I'm not sure what the issue is, since you need SysWOW64, VB6 runtimes, and other optional items to run *any* VB6 program.

Comment: thanks for the input, i checked on the platform and ServerCore-WOW64 component IS installed, and the others mandatory components too, since the offending application was installed before conversion to core and was working then (since you can convert a non core to a core server with a simple powershell command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested Sergey Merzlikin's sample application from "Writing NT service using VB6/VB5" article refrenced in the question, and observed quite different behavior. Details are below, but my guess is that Server Core installations do NOT support VB6 applications.

#### Windows 2012 with full GUI

Sample Windows service `SvSample.exe` works just fine on fresh installation of Windows 2012 with full GUI with no configuration changes applied.

#### Windows 2012 with Minimal Server Interface

Then I go from full-blown GUI to minimal interface via this PowerShell command: `Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name Server-Gui-Shell –Restart`. After that sample service still *does* work without obvious problems.

#### Windows 2012 Server Core

Then I strip down remaining bits with `Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra –Restart`. After configuration is done and server reboots, I double check that `ServerCore-WOW64` feature is still installed (without it no 32-bit application would work as I understand).

At this point sample service indeed stops working. Though not with crashes in `msvbvm60.dll`, rather Service Control Manager bluntly reports that (as seen in System event log):

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the
>   Sample VB6 Service service to connect.
>
> The Sample VB6 Service service failed to start due to the following error:
>   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

In fact, `msvbvm60.dll` is not even present in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`.

#### Conclusion

*Server Core* (as opposed to Windows 2012 in general) simply does not support VB6 runtime. I didn't check, but I'm pretty sure that situation is the same with Windows 2008 R2 Server Core too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed analysis. I am in the process of converting all my code to VB.NET, nevertheless i will try some vb6 console apps (patched with editbin /susbsystem:console to see if it works or not. I'll keep you informed.